# How Can I Use Equal And Question Mark In Category Slug?

Tags: categories, slug, htmlspecialchars-decode

I need to add a question mark and equal the category url.

**I need this:**
site.com/stack?exchange=ask

But Wordpress does not allow specific characters in url. So i tried to use html encodes in category slug. Like as
site.com/stack%3Fexchange%3Dask

Thus, the url shown with html encodes and this category does not list the products.

How can i use "?" and "=" in the category slug?

Regards

Comment: You shouldn't have those characters in the *slug*, and can't you just use `stack-exchange-ask`? Why must you use `stack?exchange=ask`? You do know that the `?` and `=` have a special meaning in the URL, don't you?

Comment: I'm trying to migration my old site. So my old URL's are bad. I thought, i can use specific characters in the category slug. Because some websites using it.(Japanese,Greek and German special alphabetic characters)